# How to check if qml component object (that is created dynamically) has been created?

Tags: qt, dynamic, components, qml, creation

I have a component that should be created dynamically.

```
Component {
    id: myComponent
    Rectangle {
        id: letItBeRect
    }
}
```

I want to create it dynamically (when some button clicked) in a function like this:

```
function loadComponent() {
    myComponent.createObject(root); //root is some root component, doesn't matter
}
```

I have state for root component that depends on some letItBeRect property:

```
state: letItBeRect.visible ? "visible" : "hidden"
```

So the question is how do I check if letItBeRect has been created, so I could assign a proper value to "state" property of root component?

I get "ReferenceError: letItBeRect is not defined" so far, which is expected from this code snippet.

P.S. This is not the real code I have, because I don't want to put commercial code here. Thank you

Comment: "letItBeRect" id is private to the inline component, so will not be seen from the outside (after all, there may be many instances of the component :) ). What you can do, is set some bool prop like "letItBeLoaded" in your loadComponent() and then check for that in the state binding.

Comment: @mlvljr I think this can do it. Though still I thought there has to be a more natural way, like a method for checking. There is a method onLoaded, but there is no method like onCreated. Thank you.

Comment: np; actually, you can set the prop from within the Component.onCompleted() of the letItBeRect itself (not the compoenent, as we need a per-instance method here), if you wish it this way.